# LINQ & Enum with Left Join

Tags: c#, linq

I have an enum

```
public enum Status { New, InProgress, Processed, InComplete};
```

I have the following query to query to give me list counts based upon the status.  But right now I'm only getting if it exists. So if Processed count is zero I won't get any values.  In SQL I would do a left join but not quite sure how to do that in LINQ. Also not sure how to do a LEFT join with an enumeration type.

Here is my query

```
var results = DbContext.Orders
                       .Where(i => i.Id== Id)
                       .GroupBy(row => new { row.Status})
                       .Select(g => new Stats()
                       {
                           Status = g.Key.Status,
                           Count = g.Count()
                       }).ToList();
```

So in sql I would do something like this.  Assuming if I had a status table.

```
SELECT status_id, s.name, count(status_id) count
FROM order o LEFT JOIN status s ON (o.status_id = s.status_id)
WHERE o.id = 1
GROUP BY status_id, s.name
```

I'm assuming I would get results like this
New         11
InProgress  5
Processed   0
InComplete  0

In my LINQ query I would not get New Processed or InComplete.

Comment: What is the type of `row.Status`? Is there any table in your DB that contains the Statuses you have mentioned? If so what are the columns of this table and how is associated with the Orders, there must be a FK constraint from Orders to Status logically? Thanks

Comment: row.Status is equal enumeration values.  So 1 = New, 2 = InProgress, 3 = Processed, 4 = InComplete.  There is no table. I only have the enumeration type.

Comment: As it is stated at the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum, *By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1.* That means New has the value of 0, InProgress the value of 1 etc.

Comment: Yeah you are right.  My mistake.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Can you write a working  query in sql of what you want?

Comment: @MindGame not a problem at all dude. Just wanted to make it clear. However you didn't ask my second question, is there any table that contains the statuses values? If so what it's schema and what is it's relation with Orders table? Thanks

Comment: @Christos.  No there is no table in the database for statuses.  I only have the enumeration to work with.

Comment: @MindGame was the `.Where` clause intended to be there?

Comment: Use Left Outer Join .  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Yes.  It suppose to be there.  I'm filtering on Id then doing the group by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to run the select in the database to get your current result, and then fill in the blanks by joining to enum in memory, like this:

```
// This selection is performed in the database
var raw = DbContext.Orders
    .Where(i => i.Id== Id)
    .GroupBy(row => new { row.Status })
    .Select(g => new Stats {
        Status = g.Key.Status,
        Count = g.Count()
    }).ToList();
// This join is performed in memory
var results =
    from e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)).Cast<Status>()
    join r in raw on e equals r.Status into rs
    from r in rs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Status = e, Count = r?.Count ?? 0};
```

Since the amount of data transferred to memory from the RDBMS does not change, joining in memory does not bring a significant change in the overall cost of this operation.