# C# LINQ GroupBy NULL Values

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an enum

```
public enum Status { New, InProgress, Processed, InComplete};
```

I'm doing a groupby using LINQ but in the database. My problem is that I have NULL values that represent the New status. So is it possible to update my NULL values to 0? Then my groupby will return counts for the new Status.

Here is my query:

```
var results = DbContext.Orders
                       .Where(i => i.Id== Id)
                       .GroupBy(row => new { row.Status})
                       .Select(g => new Stats()
                       {
                           Status = g.Key.Status,
                           Count = g.Count()
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: you can update null to 0 in row before executing the above statement or even when you pull it from database to C# object

Comment: @Rex How would I update the value?

Comment: What would be `null` there? `row.Status` can't be null as it's an enum value - a value type. If it's an `int?` you wouldn't be able to normally assign it to a field of type `Status`

Comment: @JakubDąbek It shouldn't be there.  But trying to do a workaround.

Comment: `row.Where(x=> x.Stats==null).ToList().ForEach(i => i.Stats= 0);`

Comment: @MindGame So, umm... what type is `row.Status`?

Comment: Its an integer in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ & Enum with Left Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886165/linq-enum-with-left-join)

Comment: @Scott Its not a duplicate. This previous post did not deal with NULL values in the group by clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Null Coalescing operator on your `row.Status` in your `GroupBy`, as in `row.Status ?? 0`.

Comment: Did you mean something like this:  .GroupBy(row => new { row.ProcessStatus == null ? 0 : row.ProcessStatus  }) . This code is not working.  Can you show me how I would update my code?

Comment: Thanks.  I was doing it wrong.  Just need to update my group by to this:  .GroupBy(row => new { Status = row.Status ?? 0 })

Answer (score 1):

It might look like this:

```
var results = DbContext.Orders
                       .Where(i => i.Id == Id)
                       .GroupBy(row => row.Status ?? 0) //why are you creating an anonymous class here?
                       .Select(g => new Stats()
                       {
                           Status = (Status)g.Key, //change it like that if it's the enum type
                           Count = g.Count()
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the query.